# Many forms for editing entity on one page

Tags: symfony

I have a list of objects on my page. I need to edit an object in a popup.
There are many objects, and generating many forms for each object is not correct.
What can I do, can an iframe do in a popup?

Comment: We would need to know the objects specifications, the code you have tried, your desired end-results and what is happening instead, to be able to point you in the right direction on where you went wrong and how to achieve your desired results based on the object specs. But what you are referencing can be done using a hidden absolute div, ajax or iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use iframe.

Build your form in your controller and render it in the html. The fact that it's in popup doesn't change anything. It doesn't matter if it's in popup or not, the final result will be POST call to your action.

Comment: I don’t want to render 100 forms on one page, how can I make one universal?

Answer (score 0):

You should have an action that renders a form, callable from an ajax in the view where you have all those entities.

Just change the entity id that will be received in the action as argument by changing the ajax url using js depending on the clicked entity you want to edit.

Then return with the ajax the form already rendered so with only one form you can edit as many entities (of the same class) as you want, without even need to render one form before they click which one they want to edit.